# The easiest way to mock class with org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

Tags: scala, mocking

I have a trait:

```
trait MyRepository {
    def save(dto: Dto): Unit
}
```

This trait is used by class:

```
class MyService(myRepository: MyRepository) {
    def save(obj: Object): Unit = {
        val dto = obj.toDto()
        myRepository.save(dto)
    }
}
```

and I want to test `save` method of `MyService` if it transform `obj` to `dto` properly. To do this I want to mock `MyRepository.save(dto)`. This method should return it's args.
How to do this with org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory?

```
val mockRepo = mock[MyRepository]
(mockRepo.save _).expects(dto).returning(dto)
```

?

Comment: This is described on [Scalamock](https://scalamock.org/user-guide/mocking_style/) documentation. Have you tried to run it? Which part is difficult to you?

Comment: is it necessary to use Scalamock? since you have a trait, you can just write a mocked implementation and pass it to your Service class.